# Communicate progress from future or from the promise back to the master process?

Tags: r, promise, future

Say I have this:

```
library(future)
plan(multisession)

promise = promises::future_promise({
  for (i in 1:100) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    ## SOMEHOW REPORT PROGRESS TO MAIN HERE ##
  }
  i    
})
```

In the end, it will resolve the promise with a value of 100, but how can I report each `i` value while the promise's worker is still running? What's the easiest way to do that?

I'm on windows 10, using Rstudio.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do this with `promise`, but an alternative could be to use `future.apply` and `progressr`:

```
library(future.apply)
library(progressr)

plan(multisession)

handlers(global = TRUE)
handlers("progress")

my_fcn <- function(xs) {
  p <- progressor(along = xs)
  y <- future_lapply(xs, function(x, ...) {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  p()
  })
}

my_fcn(1:100)
```

Comment: Hm, how's that possible, does progresaor do some kind of magic under the hood allowing it to communicate to the main thread? It seems this will not just work with any arbitrary function that ill define outside lapply and try to use inside

Comment: Also in this case how do i know when y is actually resolved?

Comment: as stated in [progressr intro](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/progressr/vignettes/progressr-intro.html), `future` has built-in support for `progressor`. However, I didn't find yet a way to use it directly with `promises`. Hence my workaround with `future.apply`

Answer (score 1):

I've found a proper yet simple IPC solution that made for futures to communicate arbitrary messages between child and master processes without being limited to progressr and future_lapply:

http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fellstat/ipc/blob/master/inst/doc/shinymp.html